# clone div implementation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a working javascript to clone a div and not move the other divs in the same line. But when I try to implement it in html it is not possible to close the maximized div.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java_test.js"></script>
<link href="max_css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>


<body>



<div id="box1" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('box1', 600, 600)">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('box2', 600, 600)">test2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('box3', 600, 600)">test3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten" onclick="changeSize('box4', 600, 600)">test4</div>
<div id="dummy" class="absoluteclass" onclick="changeSize('dummy', 600, 600)" ></div>


</body>
```

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
     var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var currentAbsoluteElem = document.getElementById('dummy');
     var text = elem.innerHTML;
     currentAbsoluteElem.innerHTML = text;
    currentAbsoluteElem.setAttribute('style','display:block');
     /*Extra styling neeed  to be done here*/
     
 }

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}

var absoluteCl = document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass');
absoluteCl[0].onclick = function(){
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass'))
        document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass')[0].setAttribute('style','display:none');
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.absoluteclass{
   position:absolute;
   background-color:darkgrey;
   width:600px;
   height:600px;
   left:calc(30%);
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten">test3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten">test4</div>
<div id="dummy" class="absoluteclass"></div>
```

Question: How can I implement the JavaScript function into my HTML to make the big div close by onclick?

Comment: I checked your code and bigger div closes when I click it after I clicked one of the smaller divs.

Comment: @krzysiej I know but when I want to implement it in a html like I showed in the first part of the code it doesn't close!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify your `changeSize` function like this.

```
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
   var currentAbsoluteElem = document.getElementById('dummy');
   if(id == null && weight == null && height == null){
     currentAbsoluteElem.setAttribute('style','display:none');
   }else{
     var elem = document.getElementById(id);
     var text = elem.innerHTML;
     currentAbsoluteElem.innerHTML = text;
     currentAbsoluteElem.setAttribute('style','display:block');
     /*Extra styling neeed  to be done here*/
   }
}
```

and in your html

```
<div id="dummy" class="absoluteclass" onclick="changeSize()" ></div>
```

I hope this is what you want.